# convert unsigned int to char alphabets

Tags: c

I have the following code that converts a stream data of *16-bit integer* to *unsigned 8-bit integer*.
I am looking to convert them to alphabetical data values and see what they contain.

```
#include<stdio.h>
   int main() {
        FILE *fp,*out;
        char buffer[256];
        size_t i = 0;
        fp=fopen("c:/Gosam/input.txt", "rb");
        if(fp != NULL) {
              fread(buffer, sizeof buffer,1, fp);
        }
        out = fopen("c:/Gosam/res.txt", "w");
        if(out != NULL) {
              // buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*Size);
              for( i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i += 2)
              {
                    const unsigned int var = buffer[i] + 256 * buffer[i + 1];
                    fprintf(out, "%u\n", var);
              }
              fclose(out);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

The following is the form of my output:

```
263  4294966987  4294967222  4294967032  64 4294967013  73  4294967004 90  
4294967028  83 4294966975   37  4294966961  5  4294966976   82  4294966942  
4294967022  4294966994 11 4294967024 29 4294966985 4294966986 4294966954 50  
4294966993  4294966974       4294967019 4294967007
```

This are the values I want to convert to alphabetical characters and see their content.

Comment: *Nobody* can read this. Use the post preview to edit your post into a readable form. Look at what other questions look like.

Comment: Can you show us your sample input and expected output?

Comment: please fix the indentation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read "how to ask". I did the indentation for you, but you should clearly what you are asked for.

Comment: thanks harper for the gesture, basically am new to stack overflow.

Comment: Your code treats the file "input.txt" as storage of 16 bit integers in little endian format. Your output shows the `var` as unsigned. That's a smell. Another smell is reading binary data from a file with the name `*.txt`. Do you want to make this clear? What do you call "alphabetical strings"?

Comment: After you've opened "input.txt" you're checking the variable `out` against  `NULL` - but `out` is uninitialized there. More likely you want to check `fp`.

Comment: The number `263` cannot be "converted" to readable text. The only reasonable interpretation in hex is 0x107, which are the ASCII 'characters' 1 and 7. Neither are regular text characters. The next, 4294966987, is equal to 0xFECB (assuming 16 bits), again not regular ASCII chars.

Comment: My question hasn't been answered yet though some say its ambiguous.I tried @Constantin code below but what it returned is the error "Buffer too small". I ask,how can you initialize char of undefined sized?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you expect as an answer (you didn't ask a question), but there seems to be one suspicious thing in your code:

```
char buffer[256];
```

Here `char` means `signed char`. If your code does manipulations on them (like multiplying by 256), it probably doesn't do what you expect (though I can only guess what you expect - your question doesn't mention it).

Try the following:

```
unsigned char buffer[256];
```

Also please ask a question (that is, something with a question mark), and give some examples (input, output).

Answer (score 0):

Your basic mistakes were:

- after opening the inputfile checking `out` instead of `fp` against NULL
- fread until eof won't return the number of characters that could be read (I've used [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) and [`ftell`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) for this purpose)
- writing uint values instead of char values to your file

I've fixed them and commented the affected lines appropriate. I also changed the buffer to use  [dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) instead of static allocation (that's how you can allocate memory for a buffer of a size that is unknown at compile-time). Please try the following code, which will copy all ASCII characters from one file to your output file (which is probably what you meant by 'alphabetical strings'):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE *fp, *out;
  char *buffer = NULL; /* use a pointer for dynamic memory allocation */
  size_t i = 0, charCount = 0;
  fp = fopen("c:/input.txt", "r"); /*read as ascii - not binary */
  if(fp != NULL){ /*use 'fp' here 'out' is not initalized */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); /* go to end of the file */
    charCount = ftell(fp) - 1;  /* get position */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); /* return to the beginning of the file */
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*charCount); /* allocate memory */
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char) * charCount, 1, fp); /* reads all characters from the file */
  }
  out = fopen("c:/output.txt", "w");
  if(out != NULL){
    for(i = 0; i < charCount; i += 1){ /* loop from 0 to count of characters */
      const unsigned char var = buffer[i];
      fprintf(out, "%c", var);
    }
    fclose(out);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  if(buffer != NULL){
    free(buffer); /* deallocate memory */
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Constantin- i have tried your code and it returns the error "buffer too small"

Comment: @user3559566: That means: your input file is larger than 255 bytes - so your input doesn't fit into `buffer` completly. It should still work: the first 255 Bytes from your input file are still copied into the output file.

Comment: @user3559566 Please try my updated answer - I've added `malloc` /`free` to dimension the buffer depending on your input data length.

Comment: @Constantin-actually i tried your revised code but still my output came as binary file,but at least it overcame the error. These is the form of my output . Å&ø&#ð,Ü>éKß%õ*Ó÷Ÿûõàû÷õAËïô/ÒÒÝ¢¹¼±Õí×á÷ò¥. just to make it a bit more clearer my input file is a binary file of 16-bit integer which i want to convert to human readable form.

Comment: @Constantin-the input is failing to copy and paste while if i try to add it as am image the system says i must have from 10 reputations.¿ÿèÿÜÿ±ÿÙÿ°ÿíÿøÿÀÿ and Åÿèÿäÿüÿ²ÿìÿyÿðÿÂÿáÿÿ¶ÿµÿÙÿÐÿ¤ÿ this are short parts that i have been able to scope but majority refuses

Comment: @Constantin-probably i might be wrong,my input data is I16 i think this clarity helps cause i might be assuming its int.