# convert I16 stream data to string

Tags: c

I have a data stream that contains binary data that is a I16 complex number.

I want to convert to a string representation in ANSI C.

I have tried the code below but it gives me the same binary output.

How else to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE *fp, *out;
  char *buffer = NULL; /* use a pointer for dynamic memory allocation */
  size_t i = 0, charCount = 0;
  fp = fopen("c:/input.txt", "r"); /*read as ascii - not binary */
  if(fp != NULL){ /*use 'fp' here 'out' is not initalized */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); /* go to end of the file */
    charCount = ftell(fp) - 1;  /* get position */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); /* return to the beginning of the file */
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*charCount); /* allocate memory */
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char) * charCount, 1, fp); /* reads all characters from the file */
  }
  out = fopen("c:/out.txt", "w");
  if(out != NULL){
    for(i = 0; i < charCount; i += 1){ /* loop from 0 to count of characters */
      const unsigned char var = buffer[i];
      fprintf(out, "%c", var);
    }
    fclose(out);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  if(buffer != NULL){
    free(buffer); /* deallocate memory */
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the code from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011461/convert-unsigned-int-to-char-alphabets/24013951#24013951 but you didn't mentioned I16 in the question there.

Comment: Define a function `I16toString()` and use the return value. If you have problem with the implementation asked for help for *that* function but not for such a bunch of unrelated code.

Comment: @harper- i would be glad for such a solution/implementation cause that's what am looking for.